# Opening current file in Marked with a Vim command

Tags: markdown, vim

I've been trying to create a command for Brett Terpstra's Marked app. Unfortunately I can't get it to work. On the [Marked Bonus Pack](http://support.markedapp.com/kb/how-to-tips-and-tricks/marked-bonus-pack-scripts-commands-and-bundles) page is an example for a Vim mapping and Marked, but I'd prefer to type `:Marked` to open the current file in Marked.
How am I going to do that? Adding:

```
command! Marked :silent open -a Marked.app '%:p'<cr>
```

to `.vimrc` doesn't work. (Without silent Vim gives a "file does not exist" error upon execution.)

Thanks for any help guys.

Andreas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%` is not expanded in command. You need to use expand instead. (see `:help expand`)

Something like that

```
command! Marked :silent open -a "Marked.app" expand("%:p")
```

I don't think you need the `:` (in front of `silent`) neither the `<cr>`. You are defining a command not a mapping, so you don't need to enter in command mode.

Comment: Thanks, mb14. Your answer helped a lot in finding the solution.  
The problem was not that `%` and `p` are not expanded though. 

`open` is a command used by Vim itself, so when using `/usr/bin/open` you need to tell Vim that you'd rather use that open instead of the built in function named `open` as well.  
Putting a `!` in front of open does just that. So the command needs to be:

     command! Marked silent !open -a "Marked.app" "%:p"

Comment: I'm not sure I deserve the acceptation of the answer then ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Check out the vim-marked plugin https://github.com/itspriddle/vim-marked