# Terminal vim executes open command and doesn't return back

Tags: markdown, vim

I'm using terminal Vim 7.3 on Mac OS X Lion and have the following mapping:

`map <silent> <leader>p :<C-u>silent !open -a Marked.app '%:p'<CR><C-l>`

and have also tried:

`command! Marked silent !open -a "Marked.app" "%:p"` as given in [Opening current file in Marked with a Vim command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483130/opening-current-file-in-marked-with-a-vim-command)

This works in MacVim by opening the current file in Marked.app, but in terminal vim it opens the file and doesn't return Vim to a usable state. I have to `C-z` then `fg` to get it back up.

Comment: CLI Vim is unable to fork processes, I think. Did you try with a `&` at the end of your command?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help.

Comment: No, it won't do exactly what you want because CLI Vim can't fork processes. But adding the `&` removes the need to `<C-z>`/`fg` as you only need an extra `<Return>` to come back to Vim. Because it's a limitation of Vim some people have written plugins to provide this feature : [one](https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-background-cmd), [another](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3431).

Comment: It appears it was a redraw issue. I'll post my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears terminal Vim being in an "unusable state" was actually Vim not redrawing the screen. This fixed the issue:

```
command! Marked silent !open -a "Marked.app" "%:p"
nmap <silent> <leader>p :Marked<CR>\|:redraw!<CR>
```

On a side note: MacVim doesn't have this issue. I'm sure MacVim has many other niceties that I'll miss. But running Vim in terminal has been a huge productivity boost.